# Using tf.unpack() when first dimension of Variable is None

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm feeding in a dynamic shaped Tensor using:

`x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, vector_size])`

I need to turn this into a list of Tensors that have `shape=[1, vector_size]` using `x_list = tf.unpack(x, 0)`

But it raises a `ValueError` because the length of the first dimension is not known i.e. it's `None`.

I've been trying to get around this by using another `tf.placeholder` to dynamically supply the shape of `x` but the parameter `shape` cannot be a Tensor.

How can I use `tf.unpack()` in this situation?

Or is there another function that can also turn the variable that I feed in into a list of Tensors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think you can `unpack` a tensor with the argument `num` unspecified and non-inferrable. As their [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#unpack) says:

> Raises ValueError if `num` is unspecified and cannot be inferred.

It has something to do with how TensorFlow's internal design for operations like `unpack`. In this [other tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970582/using-a-variable-for-num-splits-for-tf-split), Yaroslav Bulatov explained

> Operations like `unpack` compile into "tensor-in/tensor-out" ops during graph construction time.

Hence TensorFlow needs to know the specific value of `num` to pass compiling.

Although, I'd try to get around this by using TensorArray. (see the following code for illustration).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# assume vector_size=2 for simplicity
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
TensorArr = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
x_array = TensorArr.unpack(x)
```

[`TensorArray` is a class for wrapping dynamically sized arrays of Tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/tensor_array_ops.html). When initialize a `TensorArray` object in this application, `TensorArr = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)`, set `dynamic_size=True` and `infer_shape=False` since the shape of placeholder `x` is only partly defined.

To access each unpacked element:

```
# access the first element
x_elem0 = x_array.read(0)
# access the last element
last_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
x_last_elem = x_array.read(last_idx)
```

Then at evaluation time:

```
# generate random numpy array
dim0 = 4
x_np = np.random.randint(0, 25, size=[dim0, 2])
print x_np
# output of print x_np
[[17 15] 
[17 19]
[ 3  0]
[ 4 13]]

feed_dict = {x : x_np, last_idx : dim0-1} #python 0 based indexing
x_elem0.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
array([17, 15], dtype=int32) #output of x_elem0.eval(feed_dict)

x_last_elem.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
array([ 4, 13], dtype=int32) #output of x_last_elem.eval(feed_dict)
sess.close()
```

Note that when trying to access each unpacked element, if the `index` value is out of bound, you'd be able to pass the compiling but you'll get an error during runtime suggesting index out of bound. Additionally, the shape of the unpacked tensor would be `TensorShape(None)`, since the shape of `x` is only partially determined until being evaluated.

Comment: Currently [`unpack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#unpack) is deprecated, use `unstack()` instead (above code still works).

Answer (score 2):

Probably `tf.dynamic_partition` may help, but it requires static number of output tensors. If you can establish a maximum number of tensors then you can use it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2])
data = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,2))

parts = range(len(data))
out = tf.dynamic_partition(x, parts, 20)

sess = tf.Session()
print 'out tensors:\n', out
print
print 'input data:\n', data
print
print 'sess.run result:\n', sess.run(out, {x: data})
```

This outputs the following:

```
out tensors:
[<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:1' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:2' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:3' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:4' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:5' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:6' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:7' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:8' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:9' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:10' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:11' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:12' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:13' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:14' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:15' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:16' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:17' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:18' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition:19' shape=(?, 2) dtype=int32>]
input data:
[[7 6]
 [5 1]
 [4 6]
 [4 8]
 [4 9]
 [0 9]
 [9 6]
 [7 6]
 [0 5]
 [9 7]]

sess.run result:
[array([[7, 3]], dtype=int32),
 array([[0, 5]], dtype=int32),
 array([[2, 3]], dtype=int32),
 array([[2, 6]], dtype=int32),
 array([[7, 9]], dtype=int32),
 array([[8, 2]], dtype=int32),
 array([[1, 5]], dtype=int32),
 array([[3, 7]], dtype=int32),
 array([[6, 7]], dtype=int32),
 array([[8, 1]], dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32),
 array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: You still need to know the shape of the input. In this case, `tf.split` is simple and enough.