# Tensorflow custom loss function in Keras - loop over tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write a custom loss function in Keras, as seen in: [Custom loss function in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818584/custom-loss-function-in-keras)

My custom function is supposed to lower the effect of values smaller than 25.
To do this the function will first call `tf.clip_by_value` (thus, any values less than 25 will become 25) on both `yTrue` and `yPred` (as seen in the link above).
Next, in order to reduce the effect of these values, when a value in `yTrue` is equal to 25, the corresponding value of `yPred` will be changed to 
`yPred[i] - (yPred[i] - yTrue[i])/2`.
Finally, the function will return the result of 'binary_crossentropy' on these two tensors.

I have two main questions:

1. How do I implement this custom loss function? I am having trouble iterating over the tensors (as seen in [Looping over a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327668/looping-over-a-tensor))
2. Is the function that I proposed a good implementation to reduce the effect of these values or is there a better option?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Did you manage to modify your tensor in a custom loss ?