# Tensor flow range() integer argument expected, got Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I am trying to define a log loss function for a multi class classification problem as:

```
    self.loss = tf.losses.log_loss(
        labels=self.sampled_actions,
        predictions= [self.probability[i][self.sampled_actions[i]] for i in range(tf.shape(self.sampled_actions)[0])],
        weights=self.discounted_rewards)
```

Here, `self.sampled_actions` is a 1D tensor of `0/1/2` (e.g: `[0,1,2,1,0,2]`) which corresponds to which action is the ground truth. `self.probability` is defined as:

```
    h = tf.layers.dense(
        self.observations,
        units=hidden_layer_size,
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    self.probability = tf.layers.dense(
        h,
        units=3,
        activation=tf.sigmoid,
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

As the probabilities of all three actions, 0,1,2 for any given observation in the input.

However, when I run this program, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spaceinvaders.py", line 68, in <module>
    hidden_layer_size, learning_rate, checkpoints_dir='checkpoints')
  File "/home/elfarouk/Desktop/opengym/policy_network_space_invaders.py", line 49, in __init__
    predictions= [self.probability[i][self.sampled_actions[i]] for i in range(tf.shape(self.sampled_actions)[0])],
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Tensor.
```

Is there a way to specify that my prediction in the loss function should be dependent on the sampled_actions?

Comment: tf.shape() will return you a tensor object and saddly you cannot iterate over a tensor. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446313/using-tf-unpack-when-first-dimension-of-variable-is-none?noredirect=1&lq=1