# TensorFlow - Pad unknown size tensor to a specific size?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to pad a tensor of variable size to a given shape with a specific pad value? For example given the tensors:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4]]
```

and

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

Is there a way to have a generic operation which would take either and pad them with a value (say, to shape `[2, 4]` with value `-1`) to result in:

```
[[1, 2, -1, -1],
 [3, 4, -1, -1]]
```

and

```
[[1, 2, 3, -1],
 [4, 5, 6, -1]]
```

respectively? My reasoning (in case there is a better solution) is that I have examples from a TFRecords file, part of which has a variable length. For processing, a static length makes them easier to work with.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes. There is. Provided you do not need to change the rank of the tensor, it's very simple.

[`tf.pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) accepts regular python lists with tensors. The format of the padding is a list of pairs of how much to pad on each side of that dimension.

e.g.

```
t = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
paddings = [[0, 0], [0, 4-tf.shape(t)[0]]]
out = tf.pad(t, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=-1)
sess.run(out)
# gives: 
# array([[ 1,  2, -1, -1],
#       [ 3,  4, -1, -1]], dtype=int32)
```

---

If you want to generalise this to a useful function, you could do something like:

```py
def pad_up_to(t, max_in_dims, constant_values):
    diff = max_in_dims - tf.shape(t)
    paddings = tf.pad(diff[:, None], [[0, 0], [1, 0]])
    return tf.pad(t, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=constant_values)
# (note: see edits for the solution referred to by other answers on this question)
```

where `max_in_dims` is essentially the desired shape of the output. *Note:* this function will fail if you provide a shape that is strictly smaller than `t` in any dimension.

You can use it like:

```
t = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) # shape = [2, 2]
t_padded = pad_up_to(t, [2, 4], -1) # shape = [2, 4], padded with -1s
```

or

```
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None]) # shape = [?, ?]
t_padded = pad_up_to(t, [5,5], -1) # shape = [5, 5], padded with -1s
t_np = np.random.uniform(0, 1, [3,4]) # shape = [3,4], no padding
t_padded_out = sess.run(t_padded, {t: t_np})
t_np2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, [2,1]) # shape = [2,1], no padding
t_padded_out2 = sess.run(t_padded, {t: t_np2})
```

Although the dimension sizes are calculated dynamically, the number of dimensions is not, so make sure that `max_in_dims` has the same number of elements as t.shape.

Comment: What if t has a dynamic size (e.g., its size is determined only after some placeholder is fed)?

Comment: In my provided function, `s` is a tensor that is the shape of `t`, so the amount to pad is calculated dynamically. The number of dimensions is not calculated dynamically, so just make sure your `max_in_dims` is a vector with has the same number of elements as your `t` has dimensions. If you do this it will just work (I wrote the function with this use-case in mind).

Comment: I didn't expect it to work with a dynamic size but to my surprise, it does! Thanks!

Comment: Good reference to not waste time finding a more off the shelf solution.

Comment: This didn't really work for me in TF 2.3 with dynamic sizes since `m` is evaluated to `None` which throws an error for the subtraction. However, the fix is to simply change the line to `[[0, m - s[i]] if m != None else [0,0] for (i, m) in enumerate(max_in_dims)]`.

Comment: enumerate doesnt work in Graph Mode im afraid..

Comment: @Neeta Seems to work fine for me https://gist.github.com/Multihuntr/c744b1ae7a05bcb5611b273e1160152a (Tested on Tensorflow 2.11; latest docker image for tensorflow; I'm as surprised as you that this function still works 5 years later)

Comment: @Multihunter have you tried saving a tensorflow inference model where you're using enumerate somewhere?

Comment: @Neeta Nope! Got a code snippet to show?

Comment: @Multihunter havent had a chance to get this working for above question but this worked for me and is compatible when saving a model which creates an execution Graph as part of that process..

`paddings = tf.reshape(tf.concat([tf.constant([0]),tf.subtract(tf.shape(products),tf.shape(scores))],0),[1,2])
scores = tf.pad(scores, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=np.nan)`

Comment: I was actually asking for a code snippet to show the solution not working. :sweat_smile: Regardless, I've updated the answer with a version that should work for any exporting (based on your code snippet).

Comment: @Multihunter your original code was what didn't work. Cool thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An extension of [Multihunter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48535322/4055338) so that padding is only performed when necessary and does not yield an error for longer inputs:

Suppose we have a sequential input called `inp_seq`, which is a tensor of rank 4 and should be padded in order to have a minimum length of `filter_size` in dimension 1.

```
def dynamic_padding(inp, min_size):

    pad_size = min_size - tf.shape(inp)[1]
    paddings = [[0, 0], [0, pad_size], [0, 0], [0, 0]] # assign here, during graph execution
    return tf.pad(inp, paddings)

# Pad only if necessary
padded = tf.cond(tf.less(tf.shape(inp_seq)[1], filter_size), true_fn=lambda: dynamic_padding(inp_seq, filter_size), false_fn=lambda: inp_seq)
```

Comment: The line creating a tf.Variable is redundant, since the subsequent line overwrites it with a python list. You can remove that line and it will function the same. (Also, a `sequence` is a class defined by the python base libraries, while a `tensor` is defined by tensorflow: I think you should clarify which of these your `inp_seq` actually is; I presume that what you're dealing with is actually a sequence (or list) of `Tensors` like `inp_seq=[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]`)

Comment: I removed the redundant line, thank you for the suggestion.
The input is simply a tensor; I used the term sequence with its broader meaning (to refer to data of high dimensionality which are sequential along one dimension, namely the one to pad), I was not referring to the python base libraries. I clarified this in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar.  Not fully general, but you can do something like:

```
test_a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
test_b = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

def pad_second_dim(input, desired_size):
    padding = tf.tile([[0]], tf.stack([tf.shape(input)[0], desired_size - tf.shape(input)[1]], 0))
    return tf.concat([input, padding], 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(pad_second_dim(test_a, 4))
    # [[1 2 0 0] [3 4 0 0]]
    print sess.run(pad_second_dim(test_b, 4))
    # [[1 2 3 0] [4 5 6 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48535322/4068846) didn't work for me either and I am reluctant to do [assignments in the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721424/4068846). Here, I adjusted Multihunter's answer in such a way that it should work with variable sizes. A variation on this worked for me. Specifically, I am consuming data with `tf.data.TFREcordDataset` and wanted to apply padding on load instead of writing out the data pre-padded.

```
MIN_SIZE = 100

# v shape is undefined on the second dimension. 
v = tf.get_variable(shape=(2, None), dtype=tf.int32)

# Note: this will blow up if `padding_len` < 0
padding_len = MIN_SIZE - tf.shape(v)[-1]

# paddings = [ [0, 0], [0, padding_len] ]
paddings = tf.concat( ([[0, 0]], [[0, padding_len ]]), axis=0)

# padded.shape = (2, 100)
padded = tf.pad(t, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=-1)
```

Comment: I think what you are doing essentially is defining a tensor `paddings`, instead of a python list, to be used as an argument in `tf.pad`. In my original answer I was doing the same thing, as I would get errors otherwise. It turns out that for newer Tensorflow versions (at least 1.10), both Multihunter's solution and my newest one work.