# padding a batch with 0 vectors in dynamic rnn

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a prediction task working with variable sequences of input data. Directly using a dynamic rnn will run into the trouble of splitting the outputs according to this post:

[Using a variable for num_splits for tf.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970582/using-a-variable-for-num-splits-for-tf-split)

So, I am wondering if is it possible to pad an entire batch of sequence to make all examples have the same number of sequences and then in `sequence_length` parameter of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` I give 0 length for the padded batch of sequence. Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

These days (2022) two methods you can use to pad sequences in tensorflow are using a tf.data.Dataset pipeline, or preprocessing with tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences.

### Method 1: Use Tensorflow Pipelines (tf.data.Dataset)

The padded_batch() method can be used in place of a normal batch() method to pad the elements of a tf.data.Dataset object when batching for model training: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch

The 'batching tensors with padding' pipeline is also described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#batching_tensors_with_padding

The call signature is:

```
padded_batch(
    batch_size,
    padded_shapes=None,
    padding_values=None,
    drop_remainder=False,
    name=None
)
```

An example for your use case of inputting to an RNN is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# input is a ragged tensor of different sequence lengths
inputs = tf.ragged.constant([[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype = tf.float32)
# construct dataset using tf.data.Dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
# convert ragged tensor to dense tensor to avoid TypeError
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: x)
# pad sequences using padded_batch
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3)

# run the batch through a simple RNN model
simple_rnn = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4)
])
output = simple_rnn(batch)
```

Note that this method does not allow you to use pre-padding, the method is always post-padding. However, you can use `padded_shapes` argument to specify the sequence length.

### Method 2: Preprocess sequence as nested list using Keras pad_sequences

Keras (a package sitting on top of Tensorflow since version 2.0) provides a utility function to truncate and pad Python lists to a common length: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/pad_sequences

The call signature is:

```
tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(
    sequences,
    maxlen=None,
    dtype='int32',
    padding='pre',
    truncating='pre',
    value=0.0
)
```

From the documentation:

> This function transforms a list (of length `num_samples`) of sequences
> (lists of integers) into a 2D Numpy array of shape
> `(num_samples,num_timesteps)`. `num_timesteps` is either the `maxlen`
> argument if provided, or the length of the longest sequence in the list.
>
> Sequences that are shorter than `num_timesteps` are padded with value
> until they are `num_timesteps` long.
>
> Sequences longer than `num_timesteps` are truncated so that they fit the
> desired length.
>
> The position where padding or truncation happens is determined by the
> arguments `padding` and `truncating`, respectively. Pre-padding or
> removing values from the beginning of the sequence is the default.

An example for your use case of inputting to an RNN:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# inputs is list of varying length sequences with batch size (list length) 3
inputs = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
# pad the sequences with 0's using pre-padding (default values)
inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(inputs, dtype = np.float32)
# add an outer batch dimension for RNN input
inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis = 0)

# run the batch through a simple RNN layer
simple_rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4)
output = simple_rnn(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but are you looking for `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`?

Example (from documentation):

```
>>> from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
>>> a = torch.ones(25, 300)
>>> b = torch.ones(22, 300)
>>> c = torch.ones(15, 300)
>>> pad_sequence([a, b, c]).size()
torch.Size([25, 3, 300])
```

See the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html) here.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the `max_length` of your sequence. After that you can check if your input is less than the `max` and pad it with zero vector. 
More info here : https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/.
So in your data generator you would have to check for every input feature vector, and perform the following:

```
len_vec = feature_vec.shape[0]
if len_vec < max_length:
  mis_dim = max_length - len_vec
  zero_vec = np.zeros((mis_dim, feature_vec.shape[1]))
  feature_vec = np.vstack((feature_vec, zero_vec))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however, you are not answering the question. I know how the padding works the point is can we pad a entire batch of sequence with 0 vectors?